# Recalibrate 'full charge capacity' in Samsung notebook

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

The battery of my Samsung [NP870Z5G](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Samsung-ATIV-Book-8-870Z5G-Notebook.114298.0.html) notebook is showing rather weird behaviour: It can be charged normally and still gives 6+ hours of battery life, but the charged-value jumps at around 50% down to 0%. Windows notices this and executes a speedy shutdown. This probably isn't a Windows problem as the BIOS charge indicator shows exactly the same values. I already tried the BIOS battery recalibration, which had no effect. So the notebook is still quite usable, but it is annoying to have a device that will turn off anywhere between 40%-60% at a moment's notice.

The [results](http://output.jsbin.com/lutacegeju) of `powercfg /batteryreport` show a full charge capacity of 158Wh - far above the actual value of 91Wh, is there any way to recalibrate this?